# How to determine if a Windows user has recent document tracking enabled

Tags: windows, registry, jump-list

I'm looking for a way to programattically determine whether or not the user has Windows' "*store and display recently opened items in the Start Menu and the Taskbar*" option enabled.  I'm using the WinAPICodecPack (C#) to add items/categories to my Application's jumplist, but Exceptions are thrown when the user has the option unchecked.

Does anyone happen to know if there is a registry key, or some other method of determining the state of this settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tracking feature is disabled by the user:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced:Start_TrackDocs=0x0 (REG_DWORD)
```

When the tracking feature is disabled through Group Policy:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer:NoRecentDocsHistory=0x1 (REG_DWORD)
```

regards, Martin

Comment: Awesome, I was having a ton of trouble finding that first one.  Thanks!